# Open source SVG 2 viewer for Linux

Tags: images, image-viewer, svg

Specifically, a viewer which will render [the following figure](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#PathDataBearingCommands):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">

  <path fill="#eee"
        stroke="deeppink" stroke-width="8px" stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M 150,10
           B 36 h 47
           b 72 h 47
           b 72 h 47
           b 72 h 47 z"/>

</svg>
```

None of the alternatives I've tried seem to support bearing commands:

- JetBrains IDEA
- Inkscape
- Firefox
- GIMP
- SVG-Edit
- GNOME Image Viewer